# How to pass xsft token through cookie

Tags: jmeter, jmeter-4.0

The recorded request only have xsrf token in response header and while executing the script the xsrf token not come from database

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

1. Extract it from the response header using i.e. [Regular Expression Extractor](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Regular_Expression_Extractor), just make sure to set "Field to check" to `Response Headers`

   [image]

   textual representation of the regular expression just in case:

   ```
   YOUR_HEADER_NAME_HERE\s*:\s*(.*)
   ```
2. Once done you can add it to the next request using [HTTP Cookie Manager](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/http-cookie-manager-advanced-usage-a-guide)

   [image]

Comment: Samething i also used . everything good in my script. Setupthreadgroup passed xsrf token to teardown threadgroup . Teardown threadgroup also took that xsrf token . everything good .but teardown whole apis getting 401 error.